# Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I'm using CruiseControl.Net version 1.6.7981.1 for my continuous builds. The source control operation failed and the error message was

> ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key! FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I'm sure there is no issue with access rights as this doesn't happen all the time, and the repo exists. Is this some error on CCNET side? What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

By means of the tags from your question i assume that you're using git as source control provider.

That error message is from git and means that you're trying to authenticate with SSH and your git does not send the required ssh pubkey.

The problem could be that your ccnet is runni ng as service under a user that does not has the required ssh pubkey loaded or access to.

Please refer to the [Git Configuration Wiki Page](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Git) for further information or update your question with some more details.

Comment: But if that's the case, then CCNET shouldn't be able to pull source from git at any point of time. But this error is sporadic and I have not seen this happen many times. Most of the time, the source pull from git works fine.